# how to add a unique number|datetime|message id to an email subject with procmail

Tags: procmail

I need to change the subject of certain emails by adding a unique element. it doesn't really matter what is added as long it is unique. I thought about the date string or the message ID itself.

this is my procmail file so far:

I tried this:

```
DATE= `date`
:0fh
* Subject:.*test
| formail -I 'Subject: $DATE  test'
```

which doesn't seem to work, the result is a subject line like this:

```
Subject: $DATE  test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if you use double quotes, stuff in single quotes isn't expanded.

Comment: thanks, great, that works. as this needs an extra process per mail to get the date/time, is there a way to insert the message ID into the subject, i think this wouldn't need an extra task?

Comment: If you are using Berkeley format and/or `procmail -f` the `From_` line will contain a date stamp.  This is well-covered territory; Google for a bit.  `pm-jadate` from Jari Aalto's recipe collection is one example.  Similarly, you can grab the Message-Id into `MATCH` and put it in the Subject: header if you like, but I fail to see the utility of this.